# Valgrind invalid write size of 8

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I have some code that is suppose to break apart a string that looks like the example below and store it into a data structure.

```
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe;ON=Another Person;SN=Maybe another
```

Here is what my function looks like:

```
CalError parseOptionalParam(char * paramString, CalParam * param) {
  char * parseString = malloc(strlen(paramString) + sizeof(char*));
  strcpy(parseString, paramString);

  char * tokenSemi;
  tokenSemi = strtok(parseString, ";");
  if(tokenSemi == NULL) return SYNTAX;
  int i = 0;
  while(tokenSemi != NULL) {
    tokenSemi = strtok(NULL, ";");
    if(tokenSemi == NULL) return SYNTAX;

    char * tokenEqual = strtok(tokenSemi, "=");
    param->name = malloc(strlen(tokenEqual) + sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(param->name, tokenEqual);

    param = realloc(param, sizeof(param) + sizeof(char*));
    tokenEqual = strtok(tokenSemi, "=");
    param->value[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) + strlen(tokenEqual));
    strcpy(param->value[i], tokenEqual);

    i++;
  }
  free(parseString);
  return OK;
}
```

And here is what valgrind is telling me:

```
==7925== Invalid write of size 8
==7925==    at 0x400E56: parseOptionalParam (calutil.c:79)
==7925==    by 0x400CED: parseCalProp (calutil.c:50)
==7925==    by 0x400B0B: main (testfile.c:8)
==7925==  Address 0x5202508 is 8 bytes after a block of size 16 alloc'd
==7925==    at 0x4C2DD9F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7925==    by 0x400E13: parseOptionalParam (calutil.c:77)
==7925==    by 0x400CED: parseCalProp (calutil.c:50)
==7925==    by 0x400B0B: main (testfile.c:8)
```

The line 79 is the line that starts with `param->value[i] =` and then valgrind is referring to the `realloc` that is 2 lines above. I am confused what is wrong here? Within the `param` structure there is a flexible array member at the end of the structure which is `value`. I am simply trying to allocate another array position in the structure and then use that position for a string.

At some point in those two lines I am guessing I am doing something incorrect regarding the memory, but I am unsure what it is yet.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(paramString) + sizeof(char*));`..did you mean `sizeof(char)`?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, Surely, (or just `1`), but that's not the problem.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: that is slightly overkill, for one character extra, but should not hurt. I'm more concerned about the other `realloc`. What is `CallParam`?

Comment: @ikegami I never said that's the problem, that's why it's a comment. :)

Comment: How is CalParam declared? I'm not sure what you mean by "flexible array member"? Are you sure it's initialized correctly and points to valid memory? If it's a char* pointer, it looks like it would be dangling. And your realloc doesn't take `i` into account, so I can't see how it would not point beyond the allocated memory (which valgrind suggests) for growing i.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh, I was letting the OP know.

Comment: `param = realloc(param, sizeof(param) + sizeof(char*));` That almost can't be right. Why would the amount of space you allocate for something a pointer points to care about the size of the pointer itself? Are you confusing `sizeof(param)` with `sizeof(*param)`?

Comment: You're going to have a memory leak once you've fixed your writing out of bounds problem.  You realloc space, but you neither pass it back to the calling function nor free it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The `sizeof(char*)` is correct, it just needs a factor for the element count of the flexible array member.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld I guess, it's a member declared with `char* value[];`: An array that is declared without a size, which contains `char*`, as the assignment to `param->value[i]` indicates.

Comment: @cmaster What about the `sizeof(param)`? When you're allocating the thing the pointer points to, why does the size of the pointer matter?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That is also wrong. The size should be `sizeof(*param) + (i+1)*sizeof(char*)`.

Comment: Even if `param = realloc...` is fixed to allocate the right amount of space, the caller will not know about this (since `param` is passed by value) and so the calling code will cause UB when it tries to access the results

Comment: To get good answers you must show the definition of `CalParam` and also show the code surrounding the call to this function.  Preferably by posting a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Another problem not mentioned yet is the attempt to use nested `strtok`  (which would not cause a valgrind error, just that the function will return SYNTAX all the time)

Comment: @M.M it may help to look at my other question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024861/parsing-an-icalendar-file-in-c . I am trying to parse an ical file. My code is quite the mess. After working on this for many hours my code is falling apart and everything I try seems to not work at all. Totally open to alternatives.

Comment: I'd suggest not using `strtok`, it's a pain in the bum .

Comment: @M.M based on that question I linked to and all the "gotchas" that the ical standard has that I described in the linked post, which functions would you suggest instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Within the param structure there is a flexible array member at the end of the structure which is `value`. I am simply trying to allocate another array position in the structure and then use that position for a string.

Let's do the math: in order to allocate enough space for `CalParam` with its flexible array member that has `i` elements you need

- `sizeof(CalParam)` - that's the base size of your `struct`
- `(i+1)*sizeof(char*)` - that's an array of `char*` of size `i+1`

Therefore, your `realloc` call should look like this:

```
param = realloc(param, sizeof(*param) + (i+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

Note the asterisk in front of `param`. This is important, because `param` is a pointer.

This is not the end of the story, however, because `param` is passed by value, and you are changing its value by `realloc`-ing it. This will result in dangling reference in the caller. In order to fix this problem, you need to receive `param` pointer by pointer (i.e. a double-asterisk pointer), and assign it in your call of `realloc`, like this:

```
CalError parseOptionalParam(char * paramString, CalParam **param) {
    ...
    *param = realloc(*param, sizeof(**param) + (i+1)*sizeof(char*));
    ...
}
```

Note some more asterisks there. To make your code slightly easier to read, consider replacing the first `sizeof` with `sizeof(CalParam)`, like this:

```
*param = realloc(*param, sizeof(CalParam) + (i+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

Finally, you should also fix the potential memory leak with `realloc`: instead of assigning to `*param` directly, you should assign to a temporary, check for `NULL`, and then either assign back to `*param`, or `free` the old value and report an error.

Comment: Do I need to do `i*sizeof(char*)` though in this case? If I am reallocating each time I go through the loop it would be getting the new size of the structure wouldn't it? So each iterations `i` variable would already be included in that size?

Comment: @Fogest Oh man, you completely don't understand what `sizeof` does! The *type* isn't changing. So the size of the type isn't changing. There's no difference between `sizeof (*param)` and `sizeof (CalParam)`.

Comment: @Fogest Yes, you do need `i*sizeof(char*)` The call to `realloc` expects the total new size, not the increment on top of the old size.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I see my mistake! I was interpreting sizeof incorrectly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight probably a silly followup question, but how should I be calling the function then with the doublepointer? Should I call it the same way except instead of passing just `param` instead pass `&param`?

Comment: @Fogest Yes, that is correct: instead of passing `param`, you need to pass `&param`. This way when your function changes the value of `param`, it's automatically reflected in the caller. In other words, the caller will see a pointer to the `struct` with the newly reallocated flexible array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the following definition of `CalParam`.

```
typedef struct {
    char* name;
    char* value[];
} CalParam;
```

`sizeof(param)` is the same as `sizeof(typeof(param))`, which is the same as `sizeof(CalParam*)`, which is the size of a pointer. You probably meant `sizeof(*param)`

`sizeof(*param)` is the same as `sizeof(typeof(*param))`, which is the same as `sizeof(CalParam)`. Types are constant, so `sizeof` is known at compile-time, so flexible arrays must be ignored in the count.

As such,

```
param = realloc(param, sizeof(param) + sizeof(char*));
```

should be

```
param = realloc(param, sizeof(CalParam) + sizeof(char*)*(i+1));
```

---

Your other memory allocations are wonky too. In three places, you have something like

```
char * dst = malloc(strlen(src) + sizeof(char*));
strcpy(dst, src);
```

That should be

```
char * dst = malloc((strlen(src) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(dst, src);
```

But of course, `sizeof(char)` is `1`, so we can just use

```
char * dst = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);
strcpy(dst, src);
```

But `strdup` does the same thing.

```
char * dst = strdup(src);
```

Comment: Another problem not addressed by this post: The caller won't see changes to `param` if `realloc` moves it. You should be be passing a pointer to `param`, instead of passing `param` itself.

Comment: Okay, so you're advising using a double pointer like the other answer is describing then?

Comment: Another problem not addressed by this post: The caller has no way of telling how big the structure is. I suspect it expects an extra NULL pointer at the end of the array. If that's the case, you'll need to extend the array once more, and set `param->value[i] = NULL;`

Comment: @Fogest, Yes. That is needed.

Comment: For the other problem you are referring to the array at the end of the structure? Nothing in the spec actually says we should be adding a null pointer at the end of the array, however I likely will as I don't see any other way.

Comment: @Fogest, Can you link the spec? They may simply have forgotten. It's a very common practice. (For example, it's used when specifying the argument when executing a program.)

Comment: Sorry, by spec I am actually referring to the instructions for how the structures I have should be. For this specific project.

Comment: Another problem not addressed by this post: You repeatedly allocate strings and assign them to `param->name`. That's a memory leak. That makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple things being assigned that are used for it, but some of the assignments are before the string is split with strtok()

Comment: @Fogest, Even if you're sure that it makes sense, you still need address the memory leak. You need to free the previous string before assigning a new one to it.

Comment: I think I may need to start over on this function and focus on the parsing element first without the memory aspect, and then after that is working adding in parts relating to memory that pass data back to the function. Right now I think I am mixing too many unfamiliar concepts causing things like this question is addressing and memory leaks all over.