# Parsing an iCalendar file in C

Tags: c, regex, parsing, icalendar

I am looking to parse iCalendar files using C. I have an existing structure setup and reading in all ready and want to parse line by line with components.

For example I would need to parse something like the following:

```
UID:uid1@example.com
DTSTAMP:19970714T170000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=John Doe;SENT-BY="mailto:smith@example.com":mailto:john.doe@example.com
CATEGORIES:Project Report, XYZ, Weekly Meeting
DTSTART:19970714T170000Z
DTEND:19970715T035959Z
SUMMARY:Bastille Day Party
```

Here are some of the rules:

- The first word on each line is the **property name**
- The property name will be followed by a colon (:) or a semicolon (;)
- If it is a colon then the **property value** will be directly to the right of the content to the end of the line
- A further layer of complexity is added here as a comma separated list of values are allowed that would then be stored in an array. So the `CATEGORIES` one for example would have 3 elements in an array for the values
- If after the property name a semi colon is there, then there are optional parameters that follow
- The optional parameter format is ParamName=ParamValue. Again a comma separated list is supported here.
- There can be more than one optional parameter as seen on the `ORGANIZER` line. There would just be another semicolon followed by the next parameter and value.
- And to throw in yet another wrench, quotations are allowed in the values. If something is in quotes for the value it would need to be treated as part of the value instead of being part of the syntax. So a semicolon in a quotation would not mean that there is another parameter it would be part of the value.

I was going about this using `strchr()` and `strtok()` and have got some basic elements from that, however it is getting very messy and unorganized and does not seem to be the right way to do this.

How can I implement such a complex parser with the standard C libraries (or the POSIX regex library)? (not looking for whole solution, just starting point)

Comment: It's probably easier to use something like Bison/Flex or similar. You should check it out.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003036/toolset-to-parse-icalendar-file-in-c)? Are you trying to get a second opinion or that previous answer didn't help?

Comment: @kaylum you're correct, I did already ask the question. I have modified the example I used to be more complex and added more cases that need to be accounted for. In the previous question I felt like I underrepresented the task. The answer suggested a solution that I think would work given my example, however with how much more complex the problem can be I'm not sure that is the right solution. I feel like editing the question there unfairly invalidates the one users answer that would previously be correct.

Comment: @svens This is a part of an assignment so I am pretty limited to just sticking with C based code that won't need to rely on non system libraries.

Comment: @svens I'm referring to the regex library that while it is not ANSI C is on most systems, including Ubuntu which is what I am using. I am referring to the POSIX regex library. I can include it by using `#include <regex.h>`

Comment: @Fogest Well regular expressions are not exactly standard C either. C string parsing is never clean and simple, that's why you'd use some library in a real project. As an exercise it shouldn't be too hard to write it yourself, `realloc` and the tool `valgrind` are your friend.

Comment: @Fogest Yes, I'm aware of the POSIX library.

Comment: @svens Okay so I have coded some of this, it just seems like a less ideal way to code it but I guess I am stuck with it. What would be the best functions to use in the case of my problem? I mentioned strchr and strtok, is there anything else that may aid with this? My problem is accounting for all of the small things. Like when I get down to parsing the optional parameters and their values, I want to split at each comma in the values, however how would I check if the value is enclosed in a quote as a quote would make the value be treated literally. These are the kinds of problems making a mess

Comment: parsing isn't easy..:)

Comment: @M.M I was told on a question before that regex would be overkill for this. Would you agree? Because I experimented and came up with a regex query here that uses grouping: https://regex101.com/r/mU6iL5/1 . I could take these groups and clean those up and then parse anything else out I need from there like separating groups. Seems easier?

Comment: Your existing regex has a problem, it's picking up the `:` inside quotemarks in the mailto address. You'd have to come up with a regex that allows for the quote marks. (Maybe googling "csv regex" or "csv parsing" would give some hints - you need CSV parsing for the CATEGORIES line for example, and the considerations for CSV parsing will also help you with making the `key="value"` parser.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is supposing that you want to roll your own parser using Standard C.  In practice it is usually better to use an existing parser because they have already thought of and handled all the weird things that can come up.

My high level approach would be:

- Read a line
- Pass pointer to start of this line to a function `parse_line`:

  - Use `strcspn` on the pointer to identify the location of the first `:` or `;` (aborting if no marker found)
  - Save the text so far as the property name
  - While the parsing pointer points to `;`:

    - Call a function `extract_name_value_pair` passing address of your parsing pointer.
    - That function will extract and save the name and value, and update the pointer to point to the `;` or `:` following the entry. Of course this function must handle quote marks in the value and the fact that their might be `;` or `:` in the value
  - (At this point the parsing pointer is always on `:`)
  - Pass the rest of the string to a function `parse_csv` which will look for comma-separated values (again, being aware of quote marks) and store the results it finds in the right place.

The functions `parse_csv` and `extract_name_value_pair` should in fact be developed and tested first. Make a test suite and check that they work properly. Then write your overall parser function which calls those functions as needed.

---

Also, write all the memory allocation code as separate functions. Think of what data structure you want to store your parsed result in. Then code up that data structure, and test it, entirely independently of the parsing code. Only then, write the parsing code and call functions to insert the resulting data in the data structure.

You *really* don't want to have memory management code mixed up with parsing code. That makes it exponentially harder to debug.

---

When making a function that accepts a string (e.g. all three named functions above, plus any other helpers you decide you need) you have a few options as to their interface:

- Accept pointer to null-terminated string
- Accept pointer to start and one-past-the-end
- Accept pointer to start, and integer length

Each way has its pros and cons: it's annoying to write null terminators everywhere and then unwrite them later if need be; but it's also annoying when you want to use `strcspn` or other string functions but you received a length-counted piece of string.

Also, when the function needs to let the caller know how much text it consumed in parsing, you have two options:

- Accept pointer to character, Return the number of characters consumed; calling function will add the two together to know what happened
- Accept pointer to pointer to character, and update the pointer to character. Return value could then be used for an error code.

There's no one right answer, with experience you will get better at deciding which option leads to the cleanest code.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very informative post. You mention the following: "Save the text so far as the property name". You are referring to the text from the start of the line all the way to the colon if I am understanding this correctly? Or are you saying it should first look for a semi colon, then if that is not found go to the colon search? If it is the first option than the "property" would be including the bits with the semi colon as well.

Comment: Using the `strcspn` function (or otherwise) you can simultaneously search for `;` and `:`.  If you ever find `:` then you have finished this phase of parsing . if you find `;` then process a `key="value"` and search again for `;` and `:`.

Comment: Your text said the "property name" is the first word on each line, and the `;` and stuff after the semicolon are not part of the property name.   If your parser actually does not need to separate the parameters from the property name then your job is a bit easier.

Comment: I wish I didn't need to separate them, but I do need to separate them :/. When it finds a semi colon it should be taking the data after the semi colon until it hits the next semi colon or a colon. So I guess in the way you described it, the property name would be taken (content before a semi colon), and then I should take the text in between the next two semi colons/colons? How should I be picking out that text in between the semi colons/colons? Or should I be taking everything and passing it to the `extract_name_value_pair` function?

Comment: I described that in my answer already. The `extract_name_value_pair`starts from a given point and then indicates where it got up to .

Comment: Sorry, still confused on that function. Is the idea that I pass over the pointer to the function at the `;` starting position, and then I just extract one name, value pair and then return the next semi colon position back? Would the idea then be to keep calling such function until the pointer returned is pointing to a `:`?

Comment: Yes that's right. The calling code can't do that because it doesn't know if the next `;` or `:` is inside quotes or not, without parsing the quotes itself, and you don't want to do that twice